# My cakephp 2.2 site not working on subdomain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

My cakephp 2x site working fine on my local machine.

But i have upload on sub domain server it is not working.

I want my cakephp site working on **sub domain** with **admin Prefix**

**http://vertaxtechnology.com/ => is my domain**

**http://dev.vertaxtechnology.com/ = is my sub domain**

http://dev.vertaxtechnology.com/eventapp = is my cake directory

**This is my Root htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /eventapp/ 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**This is my app htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /eventapp/ 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**This is my webroot htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Please help thanks

Comment: Can you give us more detail about the problem? Both for our understanding and the long term value of your question.

Comment: You don't need two of the three htaccess files, only the webroot one. Then use [vhost setup](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/) to make it work. Also do that locally to be as close as possible to the real world there, as well.

Comment: i am remove first 2 htaccess file after then i have run this http://dev.vertaxtechnology.com/eventapp/admin/ url with admin prefix, it is given error 404 error (Not found).

Comment: The only thing you should need to worry about changing is your `webroot/index.php` to make sure it's pointing to the correct files